# How can we force pip to use the specified package index for dependencies?

Tags: python-2.7, pip

We have a self-hosted python package index. When I tried to install `cpplint` by

```
py -2 -m pip install cpplint -i ${self_hosted_package_index} --trusted-host ${self_host}
```

it succeeded to download `cpplint` package, but then failed to download `pytest_runner` package from `https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages` which my computer is blocked from. As a result, `pip install` failed.

I solved the problem by running `py -2 -m pip install pytest_runner -i ${self_hosted_package_index} --trusted-host ${self_host}` first.

Is there any way to force `pip install` to use the specified index for all involved packages? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pytest-runner` is declared as a dependency in `cpplint`'s `setup.py` in [`setup_requires`](https://github.com/cpplint/cpplint/blob/6b1d29874dc5d7c3c9201b70e760b3eb9468a60d/setup.py#L75). `setup_requires` dependencies are installed using [`easy_install`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html?highlight=setup_requires#keywords) which seems to doesn't know about your index URL; perhaps `pip` doesn't pass it the URL.

So no, *in this particular case* (`cpplint`) it's not possible. For most other packages it should be ok.